# about send syn tcp Packet to Scan HTTP Proxy Server by Pcap.net

Tags: tcp, pcap.net

I want to Scan HTTP Proxy Server very fast
I find a solution,i can use Pcap.net
but question is,
how can i  Scan HTTP Proxy Server by send syn tcp packet using pcap.net
there is a sample in codeplex 。but it dones't math my question

http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/402598

Comment: "Doesn't math my question"? Doesn't *match* your question? If not why not?